# Rails5 で Ransackを実装する方法

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

rails初心者で、困り果てています

検索機能をつけるため、ransackというgemを実装して、キーワード検索を自分のサイト内で行いたいと思っています。
しかし、なかなかrails5で実装を紹介しているサイトが見つからず、
古いバージョンのものでtryすると上手く動きません。

もし、rails5での実装方法や使用方法が紹介されているサイトを知ってる方いたら助けてください。

ちなみに、サイト内検索をするフォームで、キーワードを打つと１文字や２文字くらい打つと
予測を表示することはできるでしょうか？？

自分が使っているのは
Mac os 10.12.3
rails 5.0.2
です。

Comment: [githubのページ](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack)を読む限りではrails3,4,5に対応していると書いてあるので、それが動かないというのは何かやはり問題があるのでしょう。うまく動かないというエラーの部分や、サンプルとしているコード、あるいは実際のコードを提示できるなら、その方がヒントが多くなるのでアドバイスを得る可能性も高くなると思います。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> なかなかrails5で実装を紹介しているサイトが見つからず

たしかに日本語のサイトは今のところないかもしれないですね。
英語のサイトですが、rails5でransackの実装を紹介しているサイトを見つけました。
（コードが多いので英語が苦手でも大丈夫そうです）
https://richonrails.com/articles/basic-search-using-ransack

一度これを参考に実装してみて、エラーなどで詰まったら再度質問してみるのはいかがでしょうか？